# How to diagonalize a Hermitian matrix using a quasi-unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, mathematical-physics

I met a problem requiring the diagonalization of a $2n\times 2n$ Hermitian matrix $H$ in the following way:

$U^{*} HU=D$,

where $D$ is diagonal, $U^*$ is the transpose conjugate of $U$. The matrix $U$ is restricted by

$UJU^*=J$,

here $J=diag(I_n,-I_n)$ with $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Namely, $U$ is quasi-unitary.

I know how to find $D$, by diagonalizing $HJ$ using a similarity transformation, one will find

$V^{-1}HJV=JD$.

But I cannot obtain $U$ from the above $V$. How can we find the matrix $U$?

Comment: $U*$ equals $U^{-1}$ for a (quasi-)unitary matrix. If JV is quasi-unitary, then you're done, since $(JV)^{-1}=V^{-1}J^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you multiply by $J^{-1}$? Is JV not quasi-unitary?

What is the matrix V? What properties does it have? How did you get to this factorization?

Comment: I can get V using the diagonalization functions in, say, mathematica or matlab. V can be obtained by solving for the eigenvectors of HJ. However, JV is in general not quasi-unitary. For JV to be quasi-unitary, V must satisfy V*JV=J, which is not a trivial relation.

Comment: Sorry, why doesn't this follow from the fact that unitary matrices are quasi-unitary (see: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdffirstpage_1/euclid.dmj/1077490342) as well as the fact that any Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized with unitary matrices (as a result of the spectral theorem, also see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

Comment: Also since J is diagonal, it should commute with the matrices U and U*, so if you just take U to be unitary, then the quasi-unitary condition is immediately fulfilled (namely $UJU^*=JUU^*=J (UU^{-1} = J$)

Comment: I tried numerically and JV doesn't always work, so I believe not every V works. So I wonder whether we can get U given a certain V. Besides, I don't quite understand why U commute with J. For example, if U={{0,I_n},{I_n,0}}, it does not commute with J.

Comment: Your counterexample is correct, although J commuting wasn't necessary for my argument. Could you please clarify whether you are asking for help to numerically construct such a decomposition, or if you are looking for formal proof that such a decomposition must exist? It might be possible that one of the many quirks of numerical matrix multiplication is what is causing the result, in which case we would be addressing the wrong issue.

Comment: We are probably working under different definitions for quasi-unitary matrix, but I am pretty certain J only needs to be of the form $\textit{diag(I_m , I_{p-m})}$, at least according to the definition I found in that paper, in which case you could just use a unitary matrix for the diagonalization, and given the Hermitian nature of the original matrix, you are done. I am not sure how important the analogy to a symplectic matrix is for your application though.

Comment: I am willing to construct it numerically. Now I kind of understand your point, it seems that if I normalize each column v_i of V by v_i*Jv_i=+1 or -1 properly, JV will be the desired U. For a general V , JV is not U. Thanks!

Comment: Basically the normalization ensures V*JV=J.